# RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (256) must match the size of tensor b (32) at non-singleton dimension 3

Tags: tensorflow, dataset, pytorch

I just trained a model and now performing iteration on custom images with different sizes and types (.tif,,bmp,and .PNG).

I just load a model and want to generate three images, compressed, original and final images. The below code works fine when i put into training file because where i i gave CIFAR dataset for testing. Now i am giving custom images and make separate file for testing.

```
import torch
from model import End_to_end
from torch.autograd import Variable
from loss import loss_function
from grid import save_image
from torchvision import datasets, transforms

CUDA = torch.cuda.is_available()
if CUDA:
    model = End_to_end().cuda()
else:
    model = End_to_end()

EPOCHS = 20

testset = datasets.ImageFolder(root="/home/khawar/Desktop/End-to-End_IEEE-TVSCT/test/", transform=transforms.ToTensor())
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('./checkpoint/model.pth'))
print(testset.imgs)


def test(epoch):
    model.eval()
    test_loss = 0
    for i, (data, _) in enumerate(testset):
        data = Variable(data)
        final, residual_img, upscaled_image, com_img, orig_im = model(data.cuda())
        test_loss += loss_function(final, residual_img, upscaled_image, com_img, orig_im).data
        if epoch == EPOCHS and i == 0:
            #             save_image(final.data[0],'reconstruction_final',nrow=8)
            #             save_image(com_img.data[0],'com_img',nrow=8)
            n = min(data.size(0), 6)
            print("saving the image " + str(n))
            comparison = torch.cat([data[:n], final[:n].cpu()])
            comparison = comparison.cpu()
            #             print(comparison.data)
            save_image(com_img[:n].data, 'compressed_' + str(epoch) + '.png', nrow=n)
            save_image(comparison.data, 'reconstruction_' + str(epoch) + '.png', nrow=n)

    test_loss /= len(testset.dataset)
    print('====> Test set loss: {:.4f}'.format(test_loss))


def save_images():
    epoch = EPOCHS
    model.eval()
    test_loss = 0
    for i, (data, _) in enumerate(testset):
        data = Variable(data).unsqueeze(0)
        final, residual_img, upscaled_image, com_img, orig_im = model(data.cuda())
        test_loss += loss_function(final, residual_img, upscaled_image, com_img, orig_im).data
        if i == 3:
            #             save_image(final.data[0],'reconstruction_final',nrow=8)
            #             save_image(com_img.data[0],'com_img',nrow=8)
            n = min(data.size(0), 6)
            print("saving the image " + str(n))
            comparison = torch.cat([data[:n], final[:n].cpu()])
            comparison = comparison.cpu()
            #             print(comparison.data)
            save_image(com_img[:1].data, './compressed_image/compressed_' + str(i) + '.png', nrow=n)
            save_image(final[:1].data, './final_image/final_' + str(epoch) + '.png', nrow=n)
            save_image(orig_im[:1].data, './orginal_image/original_' + str(epoch) + '.png', nrow=n)

    test_loss /= len(testset.dataset)
    print('====> Test set loss: {:.4f}'.format(test_loss))


save_images()
```

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/khawar/Desktop/End-to-End_IEEE-TVSCT/test.py", line 74, in <module>
    save_images()
  File "/home/khawar/Desktop/End-to-End_IEEE-TVSCT/test.py", line 51, in save_images
    for i, (data, _) in enumerate(test_loader):
  File "/home/khawar/anaconda3/envs/End-to-End_IEEE-TVSCT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 345, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "/home/khawar/anaconda3/envs/End-to-End_IEEE-TVSCT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 385, in _next_data
    data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
  File "/home/khawar/anaconda3/envs/End-to-End_IEEE-TVSCT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 47, in fetch
    return self.collate_fn(data)
  File "/home/khawar/anaconda3/envs/End-to-End_IEEE-TVSCT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 79, in default_collate
    return [default_collate(samples) for samples in transposed]
  File "/home/khawar/anaconda3/envs/End-to-End_IEEE-TVSCT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 79, in <listcomp>
    return [default_collate(samples) for samples in transposed]
  File "/home/khawar/anaconda3/envs/End-to-End_IEEE-TVSCT/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 55, in default_collate
    return torch.stack(batch, 0, out=out)
RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [3, 288, 352] at entry 0 and [3, 256, 256] at entry 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused because you have images of different shapes.

Use `torch.reshape` to reshape the tensors to fixed dimensions (256, 256, 3).

See documentation [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.reshape.html)

Comment: Yes. I have different sizes of images. But where i do reshape?